# Referential Constraint Box Shows Too Many Fields

Tags: sql-server, edmx-designer

I am trying to set up a reference between two tables using Visual Studios EDMX Designer. The two tables have a number of fields that are named the same, these are used for logging purposes.

When I create the link, the Referential Constraint dialog is picking up these commonly named fields, and is adding them as part of the link.  See screenshot below.

[image]

Only the Id -> FrameId is needed, these other fields should not be part of the link.

How can I remove these fields from being part of the link? This is against a live database, so I don't really want to rename the columns unless I really have to.